# Recursividade de soma em python

Tags: python

Bom, to fazendo esse código que tem a finalidade de somar e imprimir recursivamente.

A variável `le` é a quantidade de vezes que quero, que seria um contador para no final informar a soma dos números escritos e `z` um parâmetro para finalizar a recursão. Só que no final imprime `None`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, explicando o porquê de ocorrer isso.

```
def soma(le,q=0,z=1):
    h = float(input("Numero:"))
    if le > z:
        return soma(le, q+h, z+1)

def main():
    q = soma(4)
    print(q)

main()
```

Comment: Junior Bgdk. A pergunta possui resposta. Ela lhe foi útil? Caso tenha o ajudado considere aceitá-la. Leia [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 1):

A sua função recursiva só tem um critério, que é quando `le > z`, quando essa verificação não for verdadeira, sua função deve retornar o resultado final.

Pelo o que eu entendi do seu código, `h` é o valor atual lido, `q` é o acumulador e `z` é o contador de chamadas recursivas.

Coloque `return q + h` no final de sua função:

```
def soma(le,q=0,z=1):
    h = float(input("Numero:"))
    if le > z:
        return soma(le,q+h,z+1)
    return q + h
```

Comment: Não prestei atenção nessa parte!! Acho que entedi!! Vou continuar praticando exercícios parecidos. Muito obrigada pela atenção e pela ajuda